# Shifting positive values in an array to offset the negative ones, in less than O(n^3)

Tags: computational-geometry

I have an array 'a' which is 1xn, and has positive and negative values. In a rolling window of size m smaller than n. I want to move backwards (to the left) the positive values of the array in order to offset the negative ones. The positive values moved, need to adopt the inverse of the shape of the negative values. Highest values must be moved first to the positions where the minimum values are located. I attach some images:

[image: The picture shows how the initial array (on top) must be transformed into the second array (below)]

[image: These pictures assume a rolling window size of 28]

Comment: Sorry; I can't understand your problem.  Can you provide a careful specification of what the desired output is?  How would I recognize whether an output is correct?  I couldn't understand it from your description.  And an example or two is not a substitute for a problem specification.  Finally, what is your question?  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a question about your problem.  Are you looking for an efficient algorithm to solve it?  Any algorithm, regardless of efficiency?  What have you tried so far?  What approaches have you considered?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, then for the first lower part you want to get rid of all the negative values:

```
g(x) = f(x)/2 + abs(f(x))/2
```

and from the second part you want to compensate the values that you added to the first part:

```
g(x + m) = f(x + m) - abs(f(x))/2 + f(x)/2
```

I denoted the new graph as g(x) and old graph as f(x).

For the place where the first part is positive, there will be no change, but for the parts where it is negative, the value is taken from the second part.

You would have to know how much to shift. And a possible problem is that compensating is still done even if the second part doesn't have a high enough value. Since you didn't give an example of that case, i cannot guess what would be the desired outcome.